# Signal diagram in TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image: Signal]

Hi, I am trying to produce this in TiKz, Is TiKz the best package to use? Any starting points on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is nothing like best package or software to use. By interchanging them, you just change one set of problems against another one. Chose one way which seems appropriate to you and stick with it.

Tikz is a powerful tool, which on the other hand can be quite time consuming sometimes even for producing simple pictures. However, it gives you the option to generate your document figures within your Latex document with the benefit of having consistent fonts and fontsize over the whole document. It is a beautiful way to typeset your documents.

Here is a starting point to your question. If anything else would be known about the curves in the graph, you could reproduce them in a more accurate manner. Here I simply imitatet the shape:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6}
            \draw[thick] (\x,3pt)--(\x,-3pt);
        \draw[->, thick] (-6.5,0) -- (7,0) node[below] {$f$ [Hz]};
        \path (-1,-3pt) node[below] {-100} (0,-3pt) node[below] {0} (1,-3pt) node[below] {100};
        \draw (-1,0) -- ++(0.3,0.6) -- ++(0.6,-0.3) -- ++ (0.1,-0.3);
        \draw (1,0) -- ++(-0.3,0.6) -- ++(-0.6,-0.3) -- ++ (-0.1,-0.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you would like to draw a given function, `pgfplots` might be an easier alternative (it uses and is fully compatible with `TikZ`). Definitely the automatic axis drawing might make it easier.